# Sql Server Object Explorer tab missing in VS 2017 RC update

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I just installed the update to VS 2017 RC and now I'm missing the Sql Server Object Explorer tab and the item in the View pulldown window at the top of VS. 
Is this a bug with the update?
I can't get to sql server object explorer to manage, look at, or edit my sql data.

I can see the databases in Server Explorer, but I'm missing some of the links in the menu when I right click on each db. Ex. missing 'new query', missing 'open in sql server object explorer'

Now when I go into the installation tool and try to repair, I get a failed message. I guess now I'm going to try and uninstall the whole VS package and try again!

[image]

Here is the log info I get when the repair fails. It looks like it might be looking for VS 2015 stuff?

> [1ab8:000a][2017-01-19T13:58:00] Error 0x80070057: 
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.BuildGraphCore(IPackage root, IEnumerable`1 packages, DependencyComparer comparer, Dictionary`2 packageIndex, Dictionary`2 nodeIndex, Boolean splitNodes)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.BuildGraph(IPackage root, IEnumerable`1 packages, Boolean isUpdate, IDependencyComparisonSeed seed)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.BuildDependencyGraph(Product product, Boolean overwrite)The root node "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional,version=15.0.25920.0" is not in the package collection.
>   Parameter name: root
>   [1ab8:000a][2017-01-19T13:58:00] Error 0x80070057: 
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.BuildGraphCore(IPackage root, IEnumerable`1 packages, DependencyComparer comparer, Dictionary`2 packageIndex, Dictionary`2 nodeIndex, Boolean splitNodes)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.BuildGraph(IPackage root, IEnumerable`1 packages, Boolean isUpdate, IDependencyComparisonSeed seed)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.BuildDependencyGraph(Product product, Boolean overwrite)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.CreateInstallOperation(Product product, String destination, ExecuteAction action)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Repair(CancellationToken token)The root node "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional,version=15.0.25920.0" is not in the package collection.
>   Parameter name: root

Update - tried to uninstall the whole VS 2017 RC package and now that is failing to uninstall with the installer tool! WTF!

Answer (score 1):

I had just installed the newly released VS2017 and did not see SQL Server Object Explorer.
i installed Entity Framework 6.1.3 then proceeded to add a new item > ADO.net Entity Data Model, started to connect to SQL server and it started installing SSDT